# How to fix missing jar files issue in android projects

Tags: android, jar

I am using SVN in Eclipse. I opened an android project and it shows errors. It says some jar files are missing. Initially I developed this project in ubuntu and now I am opening this in windows. So those jar files are referring from ubuntu file path. I have attached a screen shot as well.

[image]

I am using actionbar sherlock library and though I added it correctly it gives that error.(android support v4) , because it is referring from ubuntu file path. How to fix this errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may take these support libraries from appcompat libs folder and copy those into your project libs folder and then Add To Build Path by right click and going to add to build path. This will do the trick. Similarly you can took the neede jar files and copy those into your project